# VueJS v-model selects all the checkboxes when clicked on a single checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing an application using VueJs and Bootstrap. Multiple cards get generated using v-for. Every card has a checkbox. On hovering over a card the checkbox appears and onMouseOut it disappears, unless it is selected.

When I try selecting a single card, all cards get selected.

Here is the code:

```js
import StatsCard from 'src/components/UIComponents/Cards/StatsCard.vue'
import Card from 'src/components/UIComponents/Cards/Card.vue'

export default {
  
  data(){
    return{
      recentlySelectedFiles: [],
      allRecentFilesSelected: false,
      showByIndexRecent: null
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="i in recentFiles" class="col-xs-5ths col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths col-lg-5ths" @mouseover="showByIndexRecent = i" @mouseout="showByIndexRecent = null">
    <stats-card>

        <div slot="header" class="header-rectangle" @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.menu.open">

            <div>
                <label class="form-checkbox" v-show="showByIndexRecent === i || recentlySelectedFiles.includes(i.name)" style="margin-top: 8px;float: right;margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 0px;">
                <input type="checkbox" style="height:16px; width: 16px;" :value="i.name" v-model="recentlySelectedFiles">
                    <i class="form-icon">
                    </i>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-left: 25px;">
                <img :src="i.source" style=" height: 50px; margin-top: 50px">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div slot="footer" @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.menu.open" class="footer-rectangle" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-9"  style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="file-name-style">
                        <span>{{i.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-size-style" >
                        <span>{{i.size}} MB</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; margin-top:">
                    <div v-show="!i.shared" style="float: right; padding: 0px 5px 5px 0px; margin-right: 10px;">
                        <i class='fas fa-users' id="image"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </stats-card>
  </div>
</template>
```

What wrong am I doing? Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

`v-model="recentlySelectedFiles"` associates all your checkboxes with recentlySelectedFiles variable. So, all they are true or false at the same time

To solve it, threat your recentlySelectedFiles as an array like [false, true, false] (which indicates only your second file was selected), using  `recentlySelectedFiles[index]` (or id) in your v-model

Comment: I tried <input type="checkbox" style="height:16px; width: 16px;" :value="i.name" v-model="recentlySelectedFiles[i]">
<i class="form-icon"> </i>
It doesn't seem to work. Can you please help me out?

Comment: i is your object. You should use some distinct number that indicates a specific position inside the array. If you want, it is possible to use index in v-for (https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) and then use recentlySelectedFiles[index]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now. Also, when I select a card and hover over a different card, the checkbox on the selected card doesn't persist. What wrong am I doing here?